# org.gradle.api package is present for plugin but not it's classes?

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

The closest I could get was the org.gradle.api.plugins class, but there I don't seem to have it's other classes in my classpath?

[image: JvmTestSuite]

I've attached an image so people can see what it looks like in intellij, I'd like it to be able to find JvmTestSuite so that I can use it like:

```
testing {
    suites {
        test(JvmTestSuite) {
            sources {

            }
        }

        integrationTest(JvmTestSuite) {

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what to say.... it is on your classpath. Add `println(JvmTestSuite.class)` to your build file and it will print `interface org.gradle.api.plugins.jvm.JvmTestSuite`